# Compile OS with gcc and ld on Linux

Tags: compiling, gcc, c

I'm practicing operating system development and am having trouble getting `gcc` and `ld` to produce pure binary without any metadata or section labels. For example:

```
int function(){ return 100;}
```

would compile only this code and would not add code or metadata. So when I disassemble the code there is no extra code produced by the compiler and linker.

I am following the instructions out of [this](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf) book, I'm supposed to compile and link the C code using the following instructions:

```
$ gcc -ffreestanding -c test.c -o test.o
$ ld -o test.bin -Ttext 0x0 --oformat binary test.o
```

This is supposed to produce the following disassembled code:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
mov eax, 0xbaba
pop ebp
ret
```

However these instructions instead produced this code and a LOT of other random code, probably just the disassembler interpreting meta data as binary code.

Comment: For starters, static linking and stripping and no glibc or anything that calls system calls. I'll wait for a proper answer myself.

Comment: What are you trying to build? Some code you got, or are you trying to cook up your own? Have you looked how programs that run standalone, like [memtest](http://www.memtest.org) pulls it off?

Comment: Show the instructions, what you get and what you expect. Otherwise it is hard to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @vonbrand   I added my expectations to the above, but I did not add my results because it is quite long, basically the first part of the output is the code I expected, however after that the rest of the code is random add and pop instructions.

Comment: If it generates that, you should be OK (the ret at the end goes back; whatever comes later won't be exeecuted).

Answer (score -1):

This is what I found:

If you use the `-fno-builtin` option then `gcc` will not use the built-in C libraries.